# Upload file to GCB timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I using NodeJS to export large excel data around 400k rows in local machine took 2 minutes + only. However, after I deploy to Google cloud function, it stuck on commit file until function is timeout. I have no idea why in my local machine is fast but google function will timeout.

This is result from local machine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvlxr.png)

This is result log on google cloud
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbrpn.png)

I using google cloud function generation 1 with RAM 8.

This is full log
[image]

Comment: Did you try to supply more resources to your cloud function or increase the timeout time of it?

Comment: @FranArenas For cloud function. I allocated timeout to max 540 second,  RAM 8GB, instance max scale is 0. May I know what kind of resource I can allocate? Because I'm new player to Google cloud I'm not sure which resource can increate it.

Comment: From where do you are getting the data? Did you configure right the connection with the provider of it? Maybe your local machine is able to download data from the server but not your cloud function because permision policies on the server since it seems to be due a timeout error when comitting

Comment: @FranArenas The resources are call from API via HTTPS. According to the google log file, those `success` and `80000` is the data from my server. And, there is no much different that time consume on API to getting data from my local and cloud function. Both also around 2 minutes. However, the only different is, my local machine commit within few second but cloud function is stuck at commit until timeout

Comment: In your second screenshot, what is the HTML that is cut off?

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the html log part. In addition, I have tested around 170k data commit successfully at cloud function. But it took 6 minutes with commit only.

Comment: Can you update your question with minimal reproducible cloud function code?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. But I dont know why the problem is this. Maybe is library issues?

Change `.then` function to `await`
[image]

New Result (commit within 5 sec)
[image]